# What does the logo of each Stack Exchange site represent?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed, logo

There are many sites on the SE Network that are based on different topics. From the question topics to the identity of each site's logo, what does it represent?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Many sites have a generic logo — a speech bubble in the SE brand color containing an abbreviation for the site. This speech bubble motif also continues in some of the custom logos.

| Site | Logo | Site Topic | What the logo represents |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [**Academia**](https://academia.stackexchange.com) | [image: Academia logo] | academia | [Books](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/891/114454) |
| [**Android Enthusiasts**](https://android.stackexchange.com) | [image: Android Enthusiasts logo] | Android | The Android logo, though slightly changed to look like a speech bubble |
| [**Anime & Manga**](https://anime.stackexchange.com) | [image: Anime & Manga logo] | anime and manga | [Based on the stylized kanji for `画`](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/426/what-should-our-unofficial-community-name-and-logo-or-mascot-be/459#459) |
| [**Arduino**](https://arduino.stackexchange.com) | [image: Arduino logo] | Arduino | [An infinity symbol, based on the Arduino community logo](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/could-we-get-a-more-interesting-favicon) |
| [**Arqade**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com) | [image: Arqade logo] | videogames and videogame consoles | [The Iconic ship from the game Galaga](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4821/introducing-arqade) |
| [**Artificial Intelligence**](https://ai.stackexchange.com) | [image: Artificial Intelligence logo] | artificial intelligence | A [fingerprint](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1409), possibly related to biometrics authentication, a common application of AI |
| [**Ask Different**](https://apple.stackexchange.com) | [image: Ask Different logo] | Apple hardware or software | [the Command key found on Mac keyboards](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1356/121968) |
| [**Ask Patents**](https://patents.stackexchange.com) | [image: Ask Patents logo] | finding Prior Art on dangerous and overly broad US Patent Applications **before** they become issued Patents |  |
| [**Ask Ubuntu**](https://askubuntu.com/) | [image: Ask Ubuntu Logo] | Ubuntu | A speech bubble in the Ubuntu primary brand color ([co-designed by Canonical](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/438/158442), the speech bubble was part of [the design guidelines](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1969/158442)) |
| [**Aviation**](https://aviation.stackexchange.com) | [image: Aviation logo] | aviation | An [aircraft attitude indicator](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2996/edited-design-for-aviation-stack-exchange) |
| [**Bicycles**](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com) | [image: Bicycles logo] | bicycles and bicycling | [A head tube badge](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1004/52496) |
| [**Biology**](https://biology.stackexchange.com) | [image: Biology logo] | biology | [A stylised DNA double-helix](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3005/37956) |
| [**Blender**](https://blender.stackexchange.com) | [image: Blender logo] | blender | The logo of the Blender software, but slightly changed to look like a speech bubble |
| [**Bricks**](https://bricks.stackexchange.com) | [image: Bricks logo] | LEGO bricks and compatible building systems | A 2x2 Lego brick, a very common piece that is in over 3,000 sets. Discussed [here](https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/can-we-change-the-icon-of-the-brick-community) |
| [**Buddhism**](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com) | [image: Buddhism logo] | Buddhist philosophy, teaching, and practice | A Dharmachakra or Wheel of Dharma |
| [**Chemistry**](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com) | [image: Chemistry logo] | chemistry | A ball-and-stick diagram of Benzene |
| [**Chess**](https://chess.stackexchange.com) | [image: Chess logo] | chess | [a stylized illustration of a queen (one of the chess pieces)](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/chess-site-design-and-logo-draft/) |
| [**Chinese Language**](https://chinese.stackexchange.com) | [image: Chinese Language logo] | the Chinese language | [「漢」 The first character](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1599/18319) of the name for the Chinese script「漢字」or Chinese language「漢語」 |
| [**Christianity**](https://christianity.stackexchange.com) | [image: Christianity logo] | Christianity | An encircled Western Christian cross |
| [**CiviCRM**](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com) | [image: CiviCRM logo] | CiviCRM | [An adaptation of the CiviCRM logo](https://civicrm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23) |
| [**Code Golf**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) | [image: Code Golf logo] | coding challenges and solutions | An award medal |
| [**Code Review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) | [image: Code Review logo] | peer programmer code reviews | A magnifying glass looking at greeked code; the magnifying glass itself [looks like a `C` and `R`](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6173), although some people see a `Q`, perhaps for “question” or “(code) quality” |
| [**Computer Science**](https://cs.stackexchange.com) | [image: Computer Science logo] | computer science | a [rooted binary tree](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1189) |
| [**Constructed Languages**](https://conlang.stackexchange.com) | [image: Constructed Languages logo] | constructed languages | [The ISO 639-5 code for constructed languages](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8) |
| [**Craft CMS**](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com) | [image: Craft CMS logo] | Craft CMS | [The Craft CMS logo](https://craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like#comment12_9) |
| [**Cross Validated**](https://stats.stackexchange.com) | [image: Cross Validated logo] | statistics | [Inspired by k-fold cross-validation](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/458) |
| [**Cryptography**](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) | [image: Cryptography logo] | cryptography and cryptanalysis | Other than the letter C, it has elements of [Lock, Key, Vault, Puzzle](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/637) |
| [**Database Administrators**](https://dba.stackexchange.com) | [image: Database Administrators logo] | databases | A UML-style symbol for a database |
| [**Drones and Model Aircraft**](https://drones.stackexchange.com) | [image: Drones and Model Aircraft logo] | drones and model aircraft | UAV stands for Unmanned Aerial Vehicle, an alternate term for the subject |
| [**Drupal Answers**](https://drupal.stackexchange.com) | [image: Drupal Answers logo] | Drupal | A simplified Drupal logo |
| [**Electrical Engineering**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) | [image: Electrical Engineering logo] | electronics design | The circuit symbol for a diode |
| [**Emacs**](https://emacs.stackexchange.com) | [image: Emacs logo] | Emacs | [The letter e encapsulated in parentheses](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/402) |
| [**English Language & Usage**](https://english.stackexchange.com) | [image: English Language & Usage logo] | English language and usage | A cursive (old-style) ampersand |
| [**English Language Learners**](https://ell.stackexchange.com) | [image: English Language Learners logo] | learning the English language | a [bookmark](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2912/18673) |
| [**ExpressionEngine® Answers**](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com) | [image: ExpressionEngine® Answers logo] | ExpressionEngine | ["... an icon mark, which reflect[s] the idea of a construction project: you always start with a plan or a schematic (the outlined E) of how something needs to be built. Then, as the project is finished, the final form (solid E) is what is seen by people for all time."](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1281) |
| [**Game Development**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com) | [image: Game Development logo] | game development | Three cubes |
| [**Geographic Information Systems**](https://gis.stackexchange.com) | [image: Geographic Information Systems logo] | GIS | A compass |
| [**Graphic Design**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) | [image: Graphic Design logo] | graphic design | [The logo represents the creation process of a logo itself, with sketch lines still being visible](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/836), circles, squares and triangles being the basic shapes of any graphic design |
| [**Hinduism**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com) | [image: Hinduism logo] | Hindu religion | [Om](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om) |
| [**Home Improvement**](https://diy.stackexchange.com) | [image: Home Improvement logo] | home improvement | A cross-head screw |
| [**Information Security**](https://security.stackexchange.com) | [image: Information Security logo] | Information security | The shield represents defense; [*“the lion […] symbolizes strength and valor; the wings represent swiftness and protection”*](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/345) |
| [**Islam**](https://islam.stackexchange.com) | [image: Islam logo] | Islam | [The Kaaba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaaba), a holy site in Islam |
| [**Japanese Language**](https://japanese.stackexchange.com) | [image: Japanese Language logo] | the Japanese language | The first letter of the Japanese hiragana alphabet, which is the equivalent of the romanized letter `A` ([meta post proposing it](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/301/18189)) |
| [**Magento**](https://magento.stackexchange.com) | [image: Magento logo] | the Magento e-Commerce platform | ["...logo which captures the essence of Magento's logo, but is still unique to the community."](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/817/93120) |
| [**MathOverflow**](https://mathoverflow.net) | [image: MathOverflow logo] | research level mathematics | A minimized version of the [full logo](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/mathoverflow/Img/logo.svg), which consists of the name of the site with a visual indication of “overflow” |
| [**Mathematica**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com) | [image: Mathematica logo] | *Mathematica* | [Inspired by Wolfram’s Mathematica logo](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/547), but modified [due to copyright reasons](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/564) |
| [**Mathematics**](https://math.stackexchange.com/) | [image: Mathematics Stack Exchange Logo] | math | visually represents 6 cubes, whereas the design was made by [Jin discussed from this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/design-ideas-for-mathematics-site). |
| [**Meta Stack Exchange**](https://meta.stackexchange.com) | [image: Meta Stack Exchange logo] | the software that powers the Stack Exchange network | An empty Stack Exchange logo |
| [**Mi Yodeya**](https://judaism.stackexchange.com) | [image: Mi Yodeya logo] | Judaism | [Inspired by the Tree of Life](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1045), subtly includes the Star of David (a popular [Jewish symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_of_David)), and a question mark (with the dot being the `o` of `Yodeya`) |
| [**Movies & TV**](https://movies.stackexchange.com) | [image: Movies & TV logo] | Movies and Television | Popcorn |
| [**Music: Practice & Theory**](https://music.stackexchange.com) | [image: Music: Practice & Theory logo] | music practice, performance, composition, technique, theory, or history | [Piano Keys](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2413) |
| [**Network Engineering**](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com) | [image: Network Engineering logo] | network engineering | [Symbol for a router](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/441) |
| [**Personal Finance & Money**](https://money.stackexchange.com) | [image: Personal Finance & Money logo] | money or personal finance | A piggy-bank |
| [**Photography**](https://photo.stackexchange.com) | [image: Photography logo] | photography | A Polaroid photograph |
| [**Physics**](https://physics.stackexchange.com) | [image: Physics logo] | physics, astronomy and astrophysics | [The "Mexican Hat" potential](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/950) |
| [**Poker**](https://poker.stackexchange.com) | [image: Poker logo] | poker | A club (card suit) |
| [**Puzzling**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com) | [image: Puzzling logo] | creating, solving, and studying puzzles | [Lock + Impossible Geometry](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4630/72912); “Lock” represents riddle, mystery, and discovery; “Impossible Geometry” represents complexity, (almost) impossible to solve, mathematics |
| [**Quantum Computing**](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com) | [image: Quantum Computing logo] | quantum computing and quantum information | Logo with no discernible connection to quantum computing, adopted with no consultation with the community. (Possibly related to the logo of Strangeworks, the sponsor of the site.) Replacement proposals are being [discussed](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/89). |
| [**Raspberry Pi**](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) | [image: Raspberry Pi logo] | Raspberry Pi | [Based on the Raspberry Pi logo](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/589); *“Raspberry which symbolizes community roots and the device which is a foundation for everything you build [and] Circuit boards which are the main theme of the site”* |
| [**Role-playing Games**](https://rpg.stackexchange.com) | [image: Role-playing Games logo] | role-playing games | [a 20-sided die](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5638/41181) |
| [**Salesforce**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com) | [image: Salesforce logo] | anything Salesforce related | The Salesforce logo (a cloud with lots of connections inside) |
| [**Science Fiction & Fantasy**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com) | [image: Science Fiction & Fantasy logo] | science fiction and fantasy | [A rune circle](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/976/design-for-science-fiction-fantasy) |
| [**Seasoned Advice**](https://cooking.stackexchange.com) | [image: Seasoned Advice logo] | food and cooking | A [toque blanche (chef's white hat)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toque#Culinary) |
| [**Server Fault**](https://serverfault.com/) | [image: Server Fault Logo] | server, networking, or related infrastructure administration | There is no meta post associated with this logo, so presumably, it represents a server rack. |
| [**SharePoint**](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) | [image: SharePoint logo] | SharePoint | [The nodes represent the six functions. The cube formed by the nodes and the connecting lines convey the idea that SharePoint is a whole service package. The flow bounded inside of the cube also forms an "S."](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390/design-for-sharepoint-stack-exchange) |
| [**Signal Processing**](https://dsp.stackexchange.com) | [image: Signal Processing logo] | the theory and applications of analog and digital signal processing, image processing and computer vision | [A wave sign](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/design-for-signal-processing-stack-exchange) |
| [**Skeptics**](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com) | [image: Skeptics logo] | challenging unreferenced notable claims, pseudoscience and biased results | Based on Wikipedia's [citation needed] |
| [**Software Engineering**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) | [image: Software Engineering logo] | software development | A cup of coffee. Essential part of every software engineer life. |
| [**Software Recommendations**](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) | [image: Software Recommendations logo] | detailed software recommendations for specific purposes | [two symbols combined: a "cog (as a metaphor for software, tool, program or app) and compass (as a metaphor for guidance)"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/software-recommendations-new-site-design) |
| [**Spanish Language**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com) | [image: Spanish Language logo] | the Spanish language | the [letter ñ, typically only found in Spanish](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3051/13538) |
| [**Stack Apps**](https://stackapps.com) | [image: Stack Apps logo] | apps, scripts, and development with the Stack Exchange API | A gear |
| [**スタック・オーバーフロー**](https://ja.stackoverflow.com) | [image: スタック・オーバーフロー logo] | プログラミング | See Stack Overflow |
| [**Stack Overflow em Português**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com) | [image: Stack Overflow em Português logo] | programação | See Stack Overflow |
| [**Stack Overflow en español**](https://es.stackoverflow.com) | [image: Stack Overflow en español logo] | programación, desarrollo y uso de software | See Stack Overflow |
| [**Stack Overflow на русском**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) | [image: Russian Stack Overflow Logo] | программированию и системному администрированию | See Stack Overflow |
| [**Stack Overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/) | [image: Stack Overflow Logo] | programming | A stack of papers overflowing from an in-tray |
| [**Stellar**](https://stellar.stackexchange.com) | [image: Stellar logo] | Stellar | The official currency code for the Stellar Lumen (see Tezos for reference) |
| [**Super User**](https://superuser.com/) | [image: Super User Logo] | computer software and hardware | [an ASCII-style face](https://meta.superuser.com/a/14361/337631). |
| [**TeX - LaTeX**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) | [image: TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange Logo] | TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems | A pair of braces, ubiquitous in the TeX world, represents a group, so the official logo {T<sub>E</sub>X} is a word play that means “T<sub>E</sub>X group”. The icon { } is a short form of that. |
| [**Tezos**](https://tezos.stackexchange.com) | [image: Tezos logo] | Tezos | [The official currency code of Tezos.](https://tezos.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/can-we-get-a-different-icon#comment11_20) |
| [**The Workplace**](https://workplace.stackexchange.com) | [image: The Workplace logo] | the workplace and other career-related topics | [An origami letter O](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2331/site-design-for-workplace-se) |
| [**Theoretical Computer Science**](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com) | [image: Theoretical Computer Science logo] | **research-level** questions in **theoretical** computer science | a [deterministic finite automaton](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/701) |
| [**Travel**](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) | [image: Travel Stack Exchange Logo] | travel-related questions | three overlapping pins as discussed in [this meta post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/105447). |
| [**Unix & Linux**](https://unix.stackexchange.com) | [image: Unix & Linux logo] | Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems | U and L, short for **U**nix and **L**inux |
| [**User Experience**](https://ux.stackexchange.com) | [image: User Experience logo] | user experience | [*a combination of the two letters “UX” with a star in the middle created using negative space. The star signifies excellence, which is what the field of UX strives to achieve in product design.*](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3137/whats-the-story-behind-the-star-theme) |
| [**Veganism & Vegetarianism**](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com) | [image: Veganism & Vegetarianism logo] | vegan and vegetarian lifestyle | The "suitable for vegans" symbol |
| [**Web Applications**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) | [image: Web Applications logo] | web applications |  |
| [**Webmasters**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com) | [image: Webmasters logo] | the operation of websites |  |
| [**WordPress Development**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com) | [image: WordPress Development logo] | theme and plugin development, development and management best practices and server configuration for WordPress | The WordPress logo |
| [**Worldbuilding**](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com) | [image: Worldbuilding logo] | worldbuilding | An [unfinished world represented by a primitive sphere](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2916); the coloring is taken from a scan of a brain during the act of imagining; the [planetary ring](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2917) was added to make it more distinguishable at smaller sizes |
| [**Writing**](https://writing.stackexchange.com) | [image: Writing logo] | writing | [A stylized pencil](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2558/23927) |

Comment: Rather than guessing, I recommend you look at the various meta sites for posts like this one on math - https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/design-ideas-for-mathematics-site ... our designers have often explained their thinking when creating designs.

Comment: Everyone might have the wrong idea about the *Site Topic* right now. It should be the topic of the site, not who is availed to use it. [3D Printing SE](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/) is an example here. It's supposed to be "tools and applications of 3D printing", not "3D printing enthusiasts".

Comment: @MarkGiraffe The site topics are taken from the sites themselves, e.g. the 3D Printing banner says _“3D Printing Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for 3D printing enthusiasts. It only takes a minute to sign up.”_. The tour says _“3D Printing Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for 3D printing enthusiasts”_. What do you suggest should the source of the copy for each site topic be?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Let's look back at 3D Printing. The last sentence says "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about tools and applications of 3D printing." which means that the topic is about "tools and applications of 3D printing". So the words to be implied is right after "...every question about".

Comment: I would highly recommend not including the icons of every site on our network all on one page as individual images. This runs the risk of users who do not happen to have those individual icons stored in their local cache of getting rate limited by requesting hundreds of files from our servers all at once. Perhaps a better option is simply linking to the images for those who want to see the icon as well.

Comment: @animuson would it help if we switched the images over to imgur instead of the cdn?

Comment: @Luuklag I mean that would relieve the issue for *our* servers, but I cannot comment as to whether that would cause problems with Imgur's.

Comment: @animuson fair point. Different thought, the icons used in the top right site switcher, they're a bit scaled down in resolution, but as far as I can see, everyone who ever clicked that switcher has all these images in their cache, could we use those?\

Comment: @Luuklag The site switcher uses a giant [sprite sheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Img/favicons-sprite16.png). All of the icons are in one file and the CSS specifies the coordinates of where each site's icon is in the file. You wouldn't be able to do that in a post.

Comment: The chess logo is supposed to be a *rook*? On what basis?

Comment: @khelwood It used to be a rook. It was changed earlier this year, as the site [got its own design](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1178/your-new-site-design-is-live): I'll edit the answer.