# What should I do with my post on logos?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, meta, specific-question

I posted [Logos and their representation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359130/logos-and-their-representation) and it seems like the community doesn't support it:

[image: Screenshot]

Now I read the downvote reason, and clearly they voted the question for it being useless. However, someone had rather upvoted it instead.

My relations with reputation is something that should be dealt with at all times. This post, having a certain amount of downvotes, wrecks my rep by 8, and gained 10 afterwards.

I want to do something about my post to make it better. I already have a CW answer in the post, and it is doing alright.

What should I do with the post then? Delete? Make community-wiki? Leave it be? What will it be?

Comment: Reputation on meta is completely meaningless, unlike on the main sites.

Comment: @Polygnome This is Meta Stack Exchange, not a per-site meta. There is reputation here.

Comment: You should let it stay, we do not delete posts just because we get a downvote. It's quite trivial, sorry.

Comment: As of 2021-01-05T000407Z+0 it is 23 upvotes and 14 downvotes (+9 total).

Comment: That doesn't make reputation here any less meaningless, @SebastianSimon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like the post and I think it should be kept. Because it's useful to have all the info available in one place, and I've wondered about the meaning of the logos.

[As @Catija said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359130/logos-and-their-representation#comment1198863_359130) these kinds of posts are usually turned into community wikis, that is probably a good option.

Regardless of rep it's somewhat of a distinction being the first user to ask such a canonical question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the initial reaction to the post was quite negative, as can be seen from [your reputation history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/901680/mark-giraffe?tab=reputation). However, now that the community has taken care of it and battered it into a useful shape, both the question and answer have a decent score and I'm pretty sure it will stay this way.

The key takeaway from this story:

[image]
<sub>(source: [memegenerator.net](https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/63258239/patience-patience-my-love.jpg))</sub>

(click to view the original clip from the Lord of the Rings movie)

Comment: A cookie for giving me cheers and comfort.

Comment: lol now that's funny, you of all people using shady image hosts that are bound to rot instead of uploading to SE imgur. Break and fix? :-D

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I guess I was lazy ... though I also remember instances of not uploading images because the uploader was broken.

Comment: OK, approved. Personally I'm uploading to imgur when can't upload to SE, if they go down, all images in SE go down anyway. ;)