# Reputation and post deletion: Saving rep from downvotes

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, down-votes

In my [most downvoted question/lowest scored question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359134/what-should-i-do-with-my-post-on-logos), I had these words in it:

> My relations with reputation is something that should be dealt with at all times.

I have had some struggles with losing rep, and I'm that kind of sensitive person who doesn't want to lose value.

---

#### Now let's explain what this statement is:

I first started with [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and started with [successful posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3946752/is-there-a-fast-pattern-to-get-squared-values) that did good, and stuck there. Then I gained downvotes on other posts, and I don't blame them about it, but I was saddened that my post wasn't a good thing for the site.

Going to other sites, specifically Meta Stack Exchange (which you are at right now), I only went for answers because I wanted to help the others too. Then out of curiosity, [my first question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359130/what-does-the-logo-of-each-stack-exchange-site-represent) was released and gained the downvote spree for some time. I eventually had to post the [first question that was linked here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359134/what-should-i-do-with-my-post-on-logos), and the downvotes were solved.

To this day, the question is heavily downvoted.

---

In order to fix my relations with reputation, is it OK to delete posts (primarily questions) when they're in a bad situation (score < -2)?

Comment: You can't delete that question since it has positively scoring answers. To avoid more downvotes, it's probably best not to mention it anymore ...

Comment: Yes, if it's closed, 20K users can vote to delete it. And moderators can delete everything. But both only happen when the situation warrants it.

Comment: Flags won't do a thing except being declined by a mod as something  that doesn't need moderator intervention: The community can handle these by delete voting themselves.

Comment: Not that I personally agree with how it works but you mention losing rep, but that post has 7 x 10 = 70 from upvotes and 15 x -2 = -30 from downvotes so it's actually increased your rep by 40.

Comment: @PeterJ once a post becomes Community Wiki any rep earned by upvotes is sacrificed for the common good. IOW no rep is earned or lost on wiki posts.

Comment: Removing contributions instead of improving contributions will only result in a question/answer ban.  If a contribution receives a downvote you should address that vote by improving your contribution.  *Your goal should be to make sure that not a single one of your contributions is deleted.*  A contribution being deleted isn't a positive event.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> In order to fix my relations with reputation, is it OK to delete posts (primarily questions) when they're in a bad situation (score < -2)?

If they don't have answers, that is certainly an option. There's even an [automatic process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) that deletes them after a certain time.

If they have a (positively scoring) answer (or more than one), self-deleting is not possible. If it would be, deleting that specific question would cost the owner of the accepted answer 75 reputation. That wouldn't be fair, would it? (It wouldn't cost *me* reputation, I rep capped that day.)

Comment: Note that deleting <0 questions does attribute to a quality ban.

Comment: @rene yes, but would it really matter if a user does this themselves or Roomba does it?

Comment: For the deletion by it self it doesn't matter, for asking their next question it might ...

Comment: Also note that 'preserving reputation' is not one of the [criteria for deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/369802) mentioned in the faq. So whatever the system technically allows, it should still not be done for that reason alone.