# FAQ for Winter Summer Bash says there are no site-specific hats, but the 2cool4skool description says "(Stack Overflow only)"

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

[The FAQ page](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/faq) says:

> ### Do any sites have custom hats?
>
> No. All hats can be earned on any participating Stack Exchange site. There are also a few hats that can only be earned through meta site participation.

[The 2cool4skool hat description](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/2cool4skool) says:

> Try out the High Contrast or Dark Mode features (Stack Overflow only).

<strike>I propose the FAQ page be updated to include a caveat to say that the 2cool4skool hat can only be earned on SO sites and international SO sites.</strike>

[Catija explains in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384815#comment1283755_384815):

> we don't make hats just for specific sites, they're for features

I propose that [the FAQ page](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/faq) be updated to state that some hats may be awarded for trying features that are not yet supported on all sites (and can only be earned on supporting sites).

[What Catija suggests in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384815#comment1283806_384815) along the lines of "*'can I earn all of the hats on every site?' -> 'no, not all hats can be earned on every site'*" also works (but seems a tad vague if that's the whole gist of it and there's no more elaboration).

Comment: Better just get rid of the wrong part and just remove this part of the FAQ.

Comment: This is complicated because the answer to the question "do any sites have custom hats" *is* "No"... we don't make hats just for specific sites, they're for features and SO isn't the only site that has high contrast and dark mode... the international SOs do, too. :D Also, we don't actually change the FAQ from year to year, so naming a specific hat would cause issues next year.

Comment: @Catija ah ok. I can understand that logic... but then again, isn't the dark-mode feature currently site-specific? How about this: change the wording to add a caveat that some hats are for trying features that may not yet be supported on all sites? (edited)

Comment: I think the current discussion internally is to change the question to something more like "can I earn all of the hats on every site" and make the answer something like, "no, not all hats can be earned on every site".

Comment: My preferred solution would have been to make dark-mode available on all sites.  And I'm no superfan of dark-mode, but it is such an easy hat to get. :)

Comment: @chicks That kind of comment makes me wonder if you appreciate how non-trivial it can be to make dark mode available on a large site which was not designed from the very beginning to support it. Just to give you a taste on how it looks from an external PoV, [here's an early user-sourced "issue tracker" on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/11107541)

Comment: I absolutely recognize that the staff made the wisest call in how they handled this, but it seemed like an appropriate context for encouraging more consistency in which features are available.  I'm also perfectly content with the status quo because when I see I'm on a site in dark mode it reminds me I'm on SO itself and not StackExchange in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We've now updated that question and answer in the [Winter Bash FAQ](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/faq) to the following:

> ### Can I earn hats on all of the sites?
>
> No, some hats may only be available on certain sites.

Answer (score -3):

Just request that the FAQ be edited, or in the case of user written FAQs improve it yourself, even with a suggested edit; if you are unprivileged.

It's not really a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), that an answer is incorrect or the omission makes it wrong, when an edit adds information
that only one person needs to fix it for them. At best this should be tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion); if you are asking for advice, which is not how the question is worded.

If you could take the "times viewed" and divide by the "score" to determine the *frequency* of the asking, this is less than 10%; an iFAQ.

Hats are not *customized* for **one** particular site, as is sometimes done with our [FavIcons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359131/282094), headers and footers. No hat is site-themed or strictly available (designed/customized) for one particular site, more frequently it is that it's easier, or only possible, to obtain the hat on a limited number of sites.

The "Over 9000!" requires both a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag and a (spoiler):

> ! "... score two or greater on any network Meta site (score eight or greater on MSO or MSE)".
> That's not so much a customization, as it is a requirement.

A hat such as "Not Found" can ***truly*** be obtained on any site by anyone, but a hat such as "Heads up!", "Back In My Day", "Everything Everywhere All At Once", and a few others, would be difficult to obtain on some sites; and much easier on others.

It's not really a "customization" that the hat "Defender of the Unicorn" is only available on one site, that's a restriction; **if** the hat were available on another site it's not as though they'd have to genericize the hat; it hasn't been customized.

Comment: How does one suggest an edit to the winter bash FAQ page?

Comment: Discussion is fine, support is another option, bug seems the least correct.

Comment: Part of me is wondering if you meant to post this elsewhere, since I'm having difficulty understanding how it connects to the question post. Sorry.

Comment: The question is about a page that only SE staff can edit. There is a link, click it. We can't edit it, and we can't suggest edits to it, it is not a post and it's not a tag wiki, it's a page that belongs to winter bash site. The answer is wrong, misleading, and useless.

Comment: @Sha, clearer?!

Comment: No. From the little I can understand in your answer, it got nothing to do with the question, which is a simple "Official FAQ is wrong please change it". (Well except your first sentence "Just request that the FAQ be edited" which is exactly what this question is asking for.)